# How do i Create A Dot at the end of input bottom border

Tags: html, css, forms

I want to style an input by adding an dot at the end of it. Same As The Image Below

[image]

I've Tried To add some styling for :before :after but i couldn't figure it out

```css
.parent {
  max-width: 352px;
  width: 100%;
}

.children {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}

.the-dot {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 999px;
}

.children input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  margin-right: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type something...">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="the-dot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: https://codepen.io/markus002/pen/gOBvwYm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using flex and nesting the dot inside the line I ended up to this:

```css
.parent {
  max-width: 352px;
  width: 100%;
}


.line{
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top:15px;
  display:block;
}

.the-dot {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display:inline-block;
  float:right;
  margin-top:-4px;
  }

input {
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  outline:0;
  border:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type something...">
    <div class="line"><div class="the-dot"></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need the setup with the flex-container, instead we can use `position: relative` to create an anchor for the dot-element, which in my case will be a pseudo-element. My solution is based on this assumption.

For the placement of the red dot, we can use:

```css
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

This will place it in the right-bottom corner.
Next, I've centered the element using:

```css
transform: translate(50%, 50%);
```

The element will be placed right in the middle taking the element proportions into account. However, visually, the bottom line of the input looks one pixel off, we can manually adjust the dot to start from `bottom: 1px` instead.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  max-width: 352px;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-with-dot {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.input-with-dot::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  /* visual adjustment, because of the line-size of 1px */
  bottom: 1px;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.input-with-dot input {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="input-with-dot">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type something...">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `position: absolute` to position a dot created using `border-radius` and `aspect-ratio`:

```css
.children {
  position: relative;
}

.the-dot {
  position: absolute;
  /* 100% of .children's height, minus half its size, minus half line width. */
  top: calc(100% - var(--size) / 2 - var(--border) / 2);
  /* 100% of .children's width, minus half its size. */
  left: calc(100% - var(--size) / 2);
  /* Make it round */
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: var(--size);
  /* Ensure that its height is equal to its width */
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a pseudo-element:

```css
.children::after {
  content: '';
  /* idem */
}
```

Try it:

```css
/* Play with these */
:root {
  --size: 5px;
  --color: #f00;
  --border: 1px;
}

.children {
  position: relative;
}

.the-dot {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - var(--size) / 2 - var(--border) / 2);
  left: calc(100% - var(--size) / 2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: var(--size);
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background: var(--color);
}


/* Demo only */

.parent {
  max-width: 352px;
  width: 100%;
}

.children {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.children input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: var(--border) solid;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type something...">
    <div class="the-dot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is as below, with explanatory comments in the code; this approach has the – arguable – benefit of aiding accessibility with the use of a `<label>` element to wrap around the `<input>` and removing the presentational elements (the `.line` and `.dot` `<div>` elements):

```css
/* a simple CSS reset, to ensure that browsers use the
   the same - border-box - sizing algorithm, to include
   padding and borders in the declared element sizes,
   removing default margin and padding and ensuring that
   font properties are inherited from ancestors: */

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  /* specifying that the <body> should take up the full
     size of the viewport on the block axis: */
  block-size: 100vh;
  /* generic font styles for the page, adjust to your preferences: */
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  /* declaring padding on the block, and inline, axes: */
  padding-block: 1rem;
  padding-inline: 1.5rem;
}

.halfSize {
  width: 50%;
}

label {
  /* using flex layout: */
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  /* shorthand for:
       flex-direction: row;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
  */
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

label > * {
  /* all children of the <label> element will take
     100% of the available space: */
  flex-basis: 100%;
  /* and will have padding on their block, and inline,
     axes: */
  padding-block: 0.25rem;
  padding-inline: 0.5rem;
}

input {
  /* custom properties for the various details of the
     border we're creating;
     --borderColor is the colour of the border: */
  --borderColor: var(--borderColorStart);
  /* this is the default border-color, based on the
     color of the font; this can be updated in the CSS
     for specific elements or in the HTML "style"
     attribute, for example:
     <input style="--borderColor: lime">:
  */
  --borderColorStart: currentColor;
  /* this property defaults to the --borderColorStart
     value, but if a gradient is desired then you can
     set a different value (either here, or in specific
     rulesets for specific elements, or in the html as
     above): */
  --borderColorEnd: var(--borderColorStart);
  /* effectively acting as 'border-width', this sets the
     thickness of the horizontal gradient/line: */
  --borderSize: 0.25rem;
  /* the desired dot-color: */
  --dotColor: red;
  /* calculating where the dot should be positioned in
     order to be placed at the bottom right; the calculation
     could easily be adjusted to place it at any alternative
     position: */
  --dotPosition: calc(100% - var(--dotRadius));
  /* calculating the radius of the dot, in order to aid
     other calculations: */
  --dotRadius: calc(var(--dotSize) / 2);
  /* the size that the dot should be: */
  --dotSize: 1rem;
  /* using multiple gradients as background images to
     reproduce the line and dot: */
  background-image: radial-gradient(/* a radial gradient is used for the dot, here
         we specify a circle to be used: */
  circle, /* we use the declared --dotColor custom property,
         which extends from 0 to the calculated radius: */
  var(--dotColor) 0 var(--dotRadius), /* we then switch to transparent (to allow for the
         background-color or other background-images to
         show through without clipping) from the --dotRadius
         size extending to the full size of the gradient: */
  transparent var(--dotRadius)), linear-gradient(/* using a linear-gradient to generate the solid 'border',
         this is positioned at 90degrees so that it runs
         horizontally (0deg is vertical): */
  90deg, /* we start with the assigned --borderColorStart color value: */
  var(--borderColorStart), /* and end with the --borderColorEnd value, which defaults
         to the same declared color as --borderColorStart for a
         solid single line-colour, but can be overriden to create
         a smooth gradient: */
  var(--borderColorEnd));
  /* setting the background positions of the images, the first (radial-gradient)
     is positioned at 100% 100% (at the right bottom point), and the second
     (linear-gradient) is positioned at zero (left) and 100% of the
     element's height minus both the size of the --dotRadius and half of the
     --borderSize divided by 2, so half the --dotSize and half the --borderSize: */
  background-position: 100% 100%, 0 calc(100% - (var(--dotRadius) - var(--borderSize)/2));
  /* preventing repeating backgrounds: */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* setting the size of the background-images, the first (radial-gradient) is sized
     to be the declared --dotSize on both axes (inline and block), whereas the
     linear-gradient is sized to be full-width (100%) minus the --dotSize, and
     its height is the declared --borderSize: */
  background-size: var(--dotSize) var(--dotSize), calc(100% - var(--dotSize)) var(--borderSize);
  /* removing default element borders: */
  border: 0 none transparent;
  /* setting the padding on the block-end (the block-axis is the axis on which
     block-elements are laid out by default, vertical in the English language),
     the block-end position is the last edge of the element on the block-axis;
     this is - in English - equivalent to padding-bottom; there's a calculation
     to create the value, which is three-quarters of the --dotSize; this can -
     and perhaps should be - adjusted to your own preferences:: */
  padding-block-end: calc(var(--dotSize) * 0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <label>
    <span class="labelText">Name</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type something...">
  </label>
</div>

<div class="parent halfSize">
  <label>
    <span class="labelText">Name</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type something...">
  </label>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p4rb9yao/).

As an aside, I'm certain that this could be achieved using the `border-image` property but I – personally – cannot understand that property well enough to use it or know what I'm doing with it; others may – in time – offer such a solution which I eagerly anticipate.

References:

- [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).
- [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).
- [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position).
- [`background-repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat).
- [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).
- [`block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/block-size).
- [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).
- [`border-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image).
- [`border-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-width).
- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).
- [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
- [CSS logical properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_logical_properties).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis).
- [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction).
- [`flex-flow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow).
- [`flex-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap).
- [`font`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font).
- [`font-family`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family).
- [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size).
- [`font-weight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight).
- [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/gradient/linear-gradient).
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
- [`padding-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block).
- [`padding-block-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block-end).
- [`padding-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline).
- [`radial-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/gradient/radial-gradient).